# maven + spring mvc 3 + tiles

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jetty, tiles

I am getting the following exception when I use Maven to build spring mvc 3 + tiles example

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1058)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:329)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURL(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:276)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:251)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:58)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:239)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:65)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:222)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:204)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:154)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:123)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:54)
at org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:105)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.getDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:364)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:618)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:475)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:514)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:920)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:184)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:151)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1049)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:590)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:510)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am just following this tutorial [here](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-tiles-integration-1.html)

Please suggest some solution. I think there is some dependency issue but I am not able to find out how to resolve it and which jar is missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the digester code, it looks like you are missing SAX parser related libraries.  The one used by default is `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl`, which is present in Sun Java 1.5 and above.

One possibility is you are using an older java version. Another is you are not using Sun Java.

Answer (score 0):

May be this tutorial i came across might help you.
how to configure maven to use spring with tiles
http://makemyinfo.com/Tutorial.do?action=getTutorial&tutId=T0011.jsp